# struts2 if test for property value in arraylist

Tags: java, struts2

Class CategoryAction:

```
public class CategoryAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String catName;
    private String dispName;
    // getter and setter 
}
```

Class GAction:

```
public class GAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String category; // contains a
    private ArrayList<CategoryAction> catList; // contains a b c d e
    //getter and setter 
}
```

In my jsp page I want to check for current category.

After calling GAction in JSP page I put the following code but if part is not executing:

```
<s:iterator var="cat" value="catList">
  <s:if test="%{#category.equealIgenoreCase(#catName)}">
    if part       
  </s:if>
  <s:else>
    else part  
  </s:else>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category should NOT be an Action; an Action is supposed to handle the presentation layer, while Category is a simple POJO containing data.

And equealIgenoreCase has two syntax errors...

Modify it like follows:

Object Category

```
public class Category {

private String catName;
private String dispName;
/getter and setter 

}
```

Action Class

```
public class GAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String category; //contains a
    private ArrayList<Category> catList;//contains a b c d e
    //getter and setter 

}
```

JSP

```
<s:iterator value="catList" var="cat">
 <s:if test="category.equalsIgnoreCase(catName)">
       if part       
 </s:if>
 <s:else>
       else part  
</s:else>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am not getting when to put %{} and when not in s:if

Comment: "%{}" forces the evaluation of an ognl expression in a struts2 tag where the evaluation would not normally take place. Since the test attribute expects an expression it is redundant to use "%{}" in the test attribute however it does not hurt to do so, some people advise it for readability, personally I reserve it to override the default and so find it distracting otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrea Ligios is correct you should change modal and his approach also correct.

```
<s:iterator var="catVar" value="%{catlist}">
    <s:if test ="%{category.equalsIgnoreCase(#catVar.categoryName)}">
       if condition <br/>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
       else condition <br/>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

% is way to access value stored in the Value-stack